# Inser object tree into array/object by value

Tags: javascript

I want to use chart.js

The structure is not complete, but this doesn't mater - I think.
And I have a prototype structure for yAxes. These should be inserted 3x in
chartDef.options.scales.yAxes but BY VALUE so I can change the three parts independently.
and the ID should be inserted.
But doing like in my code, all three parts are changed to the same (last) number.

For me it looks like adding by value / by reference problem.

How can I solve?

Thank you

```
var yaxes_prototype ={
        ticks: {
            autoSkip: true,
            maxTicksLimit: 20,                      
            min: -1,
            max: 1,
            stepSize: 0.2
        }
}

    var chartDef = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: []
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            showTooltips: true,
            hoverMode: 'index',
            stacked: false,
            scales: {
                xAxes: [],
                yAxes: []
            },
        }
    }

console.log("yaxes_prototype",yaxes_prototype)
for (var i=0 ; i<3 ; i++){
    //##### OK, but BY REFERENCE
    chartDef.options.scales.yAxes.push(yaxes_prototype); 
        // OK ,insert as newobject
    chartDef.options.scales.yAxes[i]["id"]=i        
        // key,:val was added, but all val the same 
}
console.log("chartDef",chartDef.options.scales)
```

Comment: You are pushing the ecact same reference of the object to the yAxes array (three times). Changing the id will affect all of them because they are in fact the same object. Try using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yaxes_prototype))` or some other clone operation inside the `push`-method to clone the object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you send the `yaxes_prototype` exact same three times.

This snippet below may help you see if the `obj1` send as param are received exactly same object (by reference), that if you change any of it, all will change.

```js
var obj1 = {name: "foo", value: "bar"};

(function() {
        if ( typeof Object.prototype.uniqueId == "undefined" ) {
            var id = 0;
            Object.prototype.uniqueId = function() {
                if ( typeof this.__uniqueid == "undefined" ) {
                    this.__uniqueid = ++id;
                }
                return this.__uniqueid;
            };
        }
    })();
    
function printId(obj) {
  console.log(obj.uniqueId());
}

for(var i=0; i<3; i++)
  printId(obj1);
```

Thus, you should copy that and resend as different variable/object in the loop:

```js
var yaxes_prototype ={
        ticks: {
            autoSkip: true,
            maxTicksLimit: 20,                      
            min: -1,
            max: 1,
            stepSize: 0.2
        }
}

console.log("yaxes_prototype",yaxes_prototype)
for (var i=0 ; i<3 ; i++){
    var copyObj = {...yaxes_prototype}; // This copies the value stored in yaxes_prototype
    chartDef.options.scales.yAxes.push(copyObj); 
        // OK ,insert as newobject
    chartDef.options.scales.yAxes[i]["id"]=i        
        // key,:val was added, but all val the same 
}
```

Comment: Here I can change id independently. But if I change chartDef.options.scales.yAxes[i].ticks["max"]=5555 all three are changed.
So I have to do a "deep copy" like
`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yaxes_prototype))`
like [jns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70969098/inser-object-tree-into-array-object-by-value#comment125459090_70969098) say
Thank you all !!!